# Rust: implementing an iterator from a vector of std::Rc smart pointers

Tags: rust, ownership, reference-counting

I'm starting with Rust, and I'm already facing problems with data ownership.

I want to implement a generic struct called `Port<T>` that has a vector of values `Vec<T>`. Also, this struct has a vector of reference-counting pointers to other structs of the same type, `Vec<Rc<Port<T>>>`:

```rust
use std::slice::Iter;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct Port<T> {
    values: Vec<T>,
    ports: Vec<Rc<Port<T>>>,
}
```

The idea is the following: there are multiple structures of type `Port<T>`. You can add a value of type `T` to a given port. Each port stores these values in its `values` attribute. However, it is possible to "chain" one port to others using reference-counting pointers:

```rust
impl <T> Port<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { values: vec![], ports: vec![] }
    }

    pub fn add_value(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.values.push(value);
    }

    pub fn chain_port(&mut self, port: Rc<Port<T>>) {
        if !port.is_empty() {
            self.ports.push(port)
        }
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.values.is_empty() || self.ports.is_empty()
    }

    pub fn clear(&mut self) {
        self.values.clear();
        self.ports.clear();
    }
}
```

So far, the code compiles. Now, I want to implement an iterator for a port that returns references to the values owned by this port but also references to values generated by an iterator of every chained port:

```rust
pub struct PortIterator<'a, T> {
    values: Iter<'a, T>,                     // Iterates over values owned by Port<T>
    port: Option<Box<PortIterator<'a, T>>>,  // Pointer to current port iterator
    ports: Vec<Rc<Port<T>>>,                 // Pointers to remaining chained ports
}

// Note that the iterator is created from an immutable reference to Port<T>
impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for &'a Port<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;  // the iterator returns references to values
    type IntoIter = PortIterator<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        // We clone all the reference-counting pointers so the iterator owns them
        let mut ports = vec![];
        for port in self.ports.iter() {
            ports.push(port.clone())
        }
        PortIterator {values: self.values.iter(), port: None, ports}
    }
}
```

Now, let's define the `Iterator` trait for `PortIterator`:

```rust
impl <'a, T: 'a> Iterator for PortIterator<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // We first iterate over values of the original port
        if let Some(v) = self.values.next() {
            return Some(v)
        }
        // If the first iterable is done, we try to iterate over a chained port
        if let Some(port) = &mut self.port {
            if let Some(v) = port.next() {
                return Some(v)
            }
        }
        // if the chained port is over, we try to consume the next chained port
        if let Some(port) = self.ports.get(self.next_port) {
            self.next_port += 1;
            self.port = Some(Box::new(port.as_ref().into_iter()));
            return self.next()
        }
        None
    }
}
```

Now, the program does not compile. The issue seems to be in the third `if let` block, and it has to do with lifetimes. This is what the compiler says:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/modeling/port.rs:69:40
   |
69 |         if let Some(port) = self.ports.get(self.next_port) {
   |                                        ^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 57:5...
  --> src/modeling/port.rs:57:5
   |
57 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/modeling/port.rs:69:29
   |
69 |         if let Some(port) = self.ports.get(self.next_port) {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 54:7...
  --> src/modeling/port.rs:54:7
   |
54 | impl <'a, T: 'a> Iterator for PortIterator<'a, T> {
   |       ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/modeling/port.rs:71:25
   |
71 |             self.port = Some(Box::new(port.as_ref().into_iter()));
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Option<Box<PortIterator<'a, _>>>`
              found `Option<Box<PortIterator<'_, _>>>`
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this. I've been trying other options and implementations, but I keep going in circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are simpler ways of achieving what you want to achieve. Let's start small: your `Port<T>` need an `iter(&self)` method that returns an iterator that hands out `&T` items:

```
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    // ...
}
```

This function needs to chain the iterator over `self.values`, i.e. `self.values.iter()` with an iterator over chained ports. What you'd want to write is something like:

```
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    self.values
        .iter()
        .chain(self.ports.iter().flat_map(|p| p.iter()))
}
```

However, this doesn't compile because the compiler complains of a "recursive opaque type". That's because the type of `p.iter()` is our very same `impl Iterator<...>`, which would then have to contain itself. This is conceptually the same problem you encountered when building `PortIterator`, which you resolved by boxing the chained `PortIterator`. We can resolve it the same way, by boxing the inner iterator and dispatching it dynamically:

```
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    self.values.iter().chain(
        self.ports
            .iter()
            .flat_map(|p| Box::new(p.iter()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &T>>),
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, this way looks much better. I've been testing this and I've found out that, once you chain a port to another, the prior is moved and cannot be used anymore. I guess that I'll have to use `Vec<Rc<RefCell<Port<T>>>>` instead for fixing that.

Comment: @RománCárdenas I think this will work nicely, and having a method like `iter()` is convention for Rust's types, e.g. `Vec` has one.

Comment: @RománCárdenas To implement `IntoIterator` for `&Port<T>`, one could replace the closure given to `flat_map()` with a function (which should be possible because the closure doesn't capture anything) and return a type generic only over `T` from `Port::iter()`. The return type would be something like `Chain<Iter<T, FlatMap<slice::Iter<Rc<Port<T>>>, Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &T>>, fn(&Rc<Port<T>>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &T>>>`. However it didn't compile due to lifetime issues, and got really hairy really quickly. If you don't absolutely need `IntoIterator`, I'd go with this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to use Rc<RefCell<Port<T>>> for chaining the ports, but I'm facing new issues. I posted a new question with more details about my case, as you suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899965/rust-implementing-an-iterator-from-a-vector-of-stdrcstdrefcellt-smart-p